# Strange search behaviour when searching on items containing point/dot/period in field value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, keywordquery

I have a pages library containing 5 items. Each item has a field named ProjectId. The values for the ProjectId field for the 5 items are

- F.000108.01
- F.000109.01
- F.000110.01
- F.000111.01
- F.000112.01

When I do a search query on any of below values

- F.000108.01
- F.000109.01
- F.000112.01

I get the corresponding item(s). When searching on any of below values

- F.000110.01
- F.000111.01

I get no results. When searching on any of below values

- F.000110.01*
- F.000111.01*

I do get the item(s). When I search without the ".01" on

- F.000110
- F.000111

I also get the items.

When I execute the same query with the search query tool and inspect the managed properties the values in the index are indeed

- F.000110.01
- F.000111.01

So why am I not finding these 2 items? I have tried

- Index reset and full crawl
- Reindex site
- reindex pages library

### Testresult

It seems that when a ProjectId ends with 1.01 or 0.01 it can't find the item

### Another testresult

When searching F.000110.01* I find the item
When searching F.0000000000000000110.0000000001* I also find the item.

Are the number 0 or the dot/period character specials in a keyword query?

Comment: which version of SharePoint server you are using? 13, 16 or 19? And where did you perform the search? search in a library or search in a site or search in a search center?

Comment: I am using SP2013 with dec 2020 CU. Searching in search center and with rest api

Comment: Check this [article](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-specific-item-sharepoint-2013-search/). I would create a managed property **ProjectId** and set **NoWordBreaker** to true. We've solved a similar search issue with GUID values by setting this attribute to true.

Comment: I have tried this. And this only work if I search like this ProjectId=F.000110.01.
When I just put the value F.000110.01 in the searchbox it still doesn't find the item